# Complex Excel lookup with results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Column A holds all the values that are used to find/search in entries within Column B.

For example... Excel will grab all the search data from column A, if it finds any of those entries anywhere in column B then it marks the cell where it found a match as Yes in column C.

Please note that in the example below A1 is (111) and B13 is (2211122). As (111) was found within that string then it has found what it is looking for and marked it as yes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use folloiwng array formula:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND($A$1:$A$9,B1),0))>0,"Yes","No")
```

Just select `C1` cell, enter this formula in formula bar, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and then drag it down.

**UPD:**

If your substrings in column `A` has spaces in the beggining or in the end, you can use next function:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(TRIM($A$1:$A$9),B1),0))>0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: That works great! thanks. But what is we were using letters like a URL. Would that still work? For example A1 might be "http://025kc.com
" and B1 might be "http://025kc.com/117876770474390060039/posts/3vDrXupDG9A"

Comment: You need just delete last space in "025kc.com ", or use `=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(TRIM($A$1:$A$9),B1),0))>0,"Yes","No")` instead (this fromula will delete spaces in the end and in the beggining of the string)

Comment: Genius! You make it look so simple! I appreciate your time and help :)